# Counting the numbers of quantifiers, how are there 4?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, first-order-logic, quantifiers, logic-translation

From the book "Gentle Introduction to Art of Mathematics":

> How many quantifiers does this have and what kind?
>
> "Everybody has some friend that thinks they know everything about a sport.”

The answer given is "four", but no explanation has been provided.

I think that "everybody" implies Universal and "some" is Existential:

$$\forall p \in P, \exists f \in F \text{ who thinks they know everything about a sport}$$
$$P = \text{Set of all people}, F = \text{Set of Friends}$$

Perhaps we can write "everything" in some way, and I guess we can write "a sport" as "some from all the sport sets".

Comment: "to know everything about a sport" by somene (call it f) means "there is a sport such that f knows **everything** about s". Thus we have here two more quantifier: that about "some sport" and that about "everything about that sport".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Everybody has some friend that thinks they know everything about a sport.”

We have *everybody*, *some friend*, *everything*, and *some sport*:

$$∀a{\in}P\;∃b{\in}P\;∃s{\in}S\;∀t{\in}T\; \Big(Fab ∧ (Rts→Kbt)\Big).$$

Comment: Thanks, i thought about that but was confused about how to fit the knowledge about sport

Comment: @Yanjan.Kaf. Yes, in the formalisation $\exists s$ precedes $\forall t,$ whereas in the natural language sentence their order is reversed.